# Prepared statement does not print correct

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have made a prepared statement, but I keep getting printed my else statement, which in this case is 0 results. I do not get any errors in my code. Is there something I am missing here?

```
    <?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error: no connexion allowed : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); }

if(isset($_POST["headline"], $_POST["description"])) {
    $head = trim($_POST["headline"]);
    $desc = trim($_POST["description"]);
}
$query = ("SELECT headline, description FROM articles WHERE headline=? AND description=?");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $head, $describe);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($head, $describe);

$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo"[ $head -> $describe ]<br />";
      }
}

else
{ echo"[ 0 results ]"; }

$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$head, $describe` are defined where? and where's the connection for this?

Comment: use error reporting something isn't connecting or your query is failing.

Comment: *"Is there something I am missing here?"* - the connection and variables assignments

Comment: what's the point in selecting from a database exactly the same values that you supposedly already have?

Comment: It looks like that you are under the (false) impression that selected fields for some reason should be listed in the WHERE clause

Comment: Thank you a lot for the comments. I just tried to rewrite the code. Should the variables be defined correct now?

Comment: why don't you use a constant identifier to find the record? How it's supposed to be found it the description would be amended in the form? I am curious is there any sensible explanation for this code?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Just learning, so I cannot give any reasonable explanation. In case you think it would be the best idea to use a constant identifier, could you give an example of that?

Comment: First you have to explain *what* are you doing. Because, as it was mentioned before, it's impossible to make any sense from this code.

Comment: I will take a step back and study a little bit more before I go on with this question. I am a little bit confused over my code right now :)